# Messaging with JMS Spring tutorial not building [https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/#scratch]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classnotfoundexception, spring-jms

I pulled this repository https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-jms to my Windows PC and tried to build using both ./gradlew build and ./mvnw clean package. In both cases I'm getting errors and the build fails.

For Maven build, the main build error is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project gs-messaging-jms-complete: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
```

For Gradle:

```
Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
```

My Java version is currently java 17.0.6 2023-01-17 LTS. I also tried to change it to Java 11, but am getting the same issue.

I also tried to import the project into Eclipse and was able to build with Java 17 JRE, but when I'm trying to run it as a Java application, I'm getting errors:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-20T14:57:05.456-04:00 ERROR 21584 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receiver' defined in file [C:\Users\m321365\Desktop\OBPHM\Development\5.0\RC2\Code\SpringJMS\gs-messaging-jms\complete\target\classes\hello\Receiver.class]: Error creating bean with name 'myFactory' defined in hello.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myFactory' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer]: Factory method 'jmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' defined in hello.Application: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter]: Factory method 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' threw exception with message: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:605) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myFactory' defined in hello.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myFactory' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer]: Factory method 'jmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' defined in hello.Application: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter]: Factory method 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' threw exception with message: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:550) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processJmsListener(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:294) ~[spring-jms-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$1(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:248) ~[spring-jms-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$2(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:248) ~[spring-jms-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-jms-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer]: Factory method 'jmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' defined in hello.Application: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter]: Factory method 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' threw exception with message: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer]: Factory method 'jmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' defined in hello.Application: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter]: Factory method 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' threw exception with message: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' defined in hello.Application: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter]: Factory method 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' threw exception with message: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:493) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfUnique(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2098) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.jmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer(JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java:74) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter]: Factory method 'jacksonJmsMessageConverter' threw exception with message: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:94) ~[spring-jms-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at hello.Application.jacksonJmsMessageConverter(Application.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at hello.Application$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$jacksonJmsMessageConverter$1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at hello.Application$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at hello.Application$$SpringCGLIB$$0.jacksonJmsMessageConverter(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

UPDATE: I was able to build the project with Maven after updating JAVA_HOME variable to Java 17.

I am still getting the same errors when running the application. It looks like the error comes from this bean:

```
@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
```

I can open MappingJackson2MessageConverter declaration in my IDE, but when I'm putting a breakpoint there and run in debug mode, I'm getting "ClassNotFoundException". Why is it not finding this class? What did I miss? There are no errors in the project that I can see.

Comment: Double-check the configuration of your `JAVA_HOME` and perhaps your `PATH` as well. The Maven and Gradle errors are both because you're running them on Java 11 and Spring Boot's build plugins require Java 17. You can double-check the version of Java that's being used by running `./mvnw -version` or `./gradlew -version`.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to build after I checked and updated JAVA_HOME and PATH variables, however when i'm running the application, I'm getting the same error stack as I posted above from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in the guide that were introduced when it switched from Apache ActiveMQ to Apache Artemis. I've opened [a pull request](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-jms/pull/38) to correct them. You can make the same changes yourself and the guide should work. You need to:

1. Add a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json`
2. Add a dependency on `org.apache.activemq:artemis-jakarta-server`
3. Create an `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources` that contains `spring.artemis.mode=embedded`

With these changes in place, the application should start and successfully send and receive a message.

Comment: Awesome! This worked and I was able to run it - thank you!